# Save array of items in UserDefaults - iOS 12

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, userdefaults

I want to save an array of `TreeWithPos` objects in UserDefaults. Every solution I've found (like Data object) didn't work in iOS 12.
What can I do?
I've tried this:

```
try? defaults.set(NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: treesArr, requiringSecureCoding: false), forKey: "trees")
```

Comment: share what you tried

Comment: It is probably easier to have your object implement `Codable` and encode it to a JSON string that you then store in `UserDefaults`

Comment: You need to show more code; specifically the definition of the object inside `treesArr`

Comment: Do not store your data in UserDefaults. And don't bother with `NSKeyedArchiver`. Use Swift serialization and write the data to a file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try using `Codable` protocol with `JSONEncoder()` & `JSONDecoder()`

```
struct SaveItem : Codable {

    var name:String
}
```

//

```
let arr = [SaveItem(name: "name1"),SaveItem(name: "name2")]

do {

    // write

    var data  = try JSONEncoder().encode(arr)

    UserDefaults.standard.set(data, forKey: "Key")

    // read

    let content = UserDefaults.standard.data(forKey: "Key")

    let saved = try JSONDecoder().decode([SaveItem].self, from: content!)

    print(saved)

 }
 catch {

      print(error)
  }
```

Comment: I got an error: "Type 'TreeWithPos' does not conform to protocol 'Decodable'"

Comment: convert it to **struct TreeWithPos : Codable {**

Comment: Do you have Type **NSNumber** , **Any**  or any other custom type that doesn't conform to **Codable** inside that struct ??